# Elasticsearch and auto_query

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

In the database objects are named `news` and `news test`

```
class ItemIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True)
    name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='name')
    name_alt = indexes.CharField(model_attr='name_alt')

    def get_model(self):
        return Serial

>>> from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
>>> sqs = SearchQuerySet().all()
>>> sqs.count()
4
>>> SearchQuerySet().auto_query('new') # not working all query!
[]
```

If use `haystack.backends.simple_backend.SimpleEngine` its working.

Django==1.5.1

Elasticsearch==0.90

django-haystack==master (2.0)

Why????

Comment: Having you indexed Elasticsearch? Your question states that these objects are in the database, but you can only query objects in the search engine after they've been indexed.

Comment: How to check? `./manage.py rebuild_index` does not give errors.

Comment: `curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/haystack/modelresult/_search?q=new`
work! 
`{"took":2,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":1,"max_score":0.11506981,"hits":[{"_index":"haystack","_type":"modelresult","_id":"serials.serial.2","_score":0.11506981, "_source" : {"django_id": "2", "name": "News", "text": null, "genres": [1], "django_ct": "serials.serial", "id": "serials.serial.2", "name_alt": ""}}]}}` SearchQuerySet().auto_query('new') - not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It doesn't look like you're populating the all import document field.**

Your `SearchIndex` class has these fields:

```
text = indexes.CharField(document=True)
name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='name')
name_alt = indexes.CharField(model_attr='name_alt')
```

You've defined the data source for `name` and `name_alt` but not for `text`. The output from your command line search shows that that field is empty in the search index. You have several options:

- Populate that field from a model attribute
- Use a [`prepare_FOO`](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchindex_api.html#prepare-foo-self-object) method to prepare the content for that field
- Use a template, using the [`use_template` argument](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchfield_api.html?highlight=template#use-template) for the `text` field and include any and all content in that template

Now the follow up question is why did `auto_query` fail but a basic curl query work? Because [`auto_query` is searching the content](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html#auto-query) - the document - and that's missing.

Comment: Very strange. On creation prepare_content said nothing in the documentation. And why it works if you use SimpleEngine?

Comment: "The simple backend using very basic matching via the database itself. It’s not recommended for production use but it will return results." https://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html?highlight=SimpleEngine#simple

The search engine is another data store. Haystack gives you the tools to map your data to the search index, add it to the search index, and query it - but you still have to prepare the data and move it into the index.